# Google Cloud Task is not writing file to storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-app-engine-python, google-cloud-tasks

I am working on a GAE app, one of the time consuming task, I have moved to Cloud Tasks. This task is supposed to read files from storage, process it and write final output back to the storage bucket.

Everything goes fine till generating the data, but task hangs before writing the output file back to cloud storage. Task remains continuously in running state without any error logs.

This code runs successfully if I run it as a manual python script.

I wonder if there is a permission thing that is blocking cloud task to write back to storage bucket.
Any lead on this is appreciated.

Edit: Problem appears in the path. output file path is something like: /logger_sh2 (1)/sh2_day4.

It works well for other paths.

Comment: can you share the piece of code where you write the file to storage?

Comment: Any updates on this? Can you share the code snippet that stores the file? If you solved it, please write it as an answer